# Array modification dosn't work in Ractive JS

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I'm trying to push item into array and it doesn't appear in HTML.

The example of code:

```
<script type="text/" id="tmpl">
<button on-click="create" type="button">Create</button>
{{#items}}{{.}},{{/items}}
</script>

<body>

<div id="container">
</div>

</body>

var model = {items: [1, 2, 3, 4]};

var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: "#container",
  template: "#tmpl",
  data: model
});

ractive.on("create", function() {
  model.items.push(7);
  console.log(model.items);
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWzJNR

What is wrong?

Comment: Code form example http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/array-modification doesn't work too

Comment: You can use `ractive.push('items', 7);` instead of `model.items.push(7);`

Comment: It's not solution because I can update model outside of Ractive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magic mode and array modification is turned off by default in 0.8 and pending removal in 0.9 (they'll be done externally via an adaptor instead).

For 0.8, you can manually set `modifyArrays` configuration to `true`. Alternatively, simply using Ractive's built-in array methods as mentioned in the comments should work provided that you have a reference to the instance.